# Databinding issue with custom combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a custom read only combobox that works for the most part.  However when I download data from an external source, and set up data binding there is some very odd behaviour.  Please look at the code below:

```
cboGender.DataSource = Animal.SpecificGenders;
cboGender.DataBindings.Clear();
cboGender.DataBindings.Add("text", animal, "Gender");

((ReadOnlyComboBox)cboGender).Readonly = true;
```

When the above line hits, it calls this property:

```
public bool Readonly 
    { 
        get
        {
            return readOnly;
        }

        set
        {
            textBox.Text = this.Text;
            ShowControl();
            readOnly = value;
        }
    }
```

Now, my issue is that when I set ReadOnly to false, this works fine.  The 'this.Text' in the above setter shows the value that has been bound to it.  However when I set the Reaonly to true, the 'this.Text' shows an empty string.  This is the only difference I make.  The this.Text refers to the standard Combobox Text property.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The base ComboBox has a DropDownStyle property that can be set to DropDownList which essentially makes the ComboBox read only.  Maybe you could do that instead of implementing your own ReadOnly property.

If not, I suspect your problem exists in the ShowControl() method. Even though you're first setting the textBox.Text property, something in the ShowControl() method is preventing the control from updating.  And, actually, setting another property from this Property doesn't seem quite right to me.

You're already using DataBinding, so setting the Text property should already be handled elsewhere.